# Batch job is stuck at STARTING when submited from a JMS Listener onMessage()

Tags: java, jms, glassfish-4.1, activemq-artemis, jsr352

I'm trying to start batch jobs according to JSR 352 specifications using `JobOperator` obtained from BatchRuntime in an `onMessage(...)` method in a JMS MessageListener.

```
JobOperator jobOperator = BatchRuntime.getJobOperator();
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("sourceFile", "data_file.csv");
jobOperator.start("batchTask", props);
```

The result is that the job execution is stuck at STARTING. When I try to stop the task from the same thread, it is similarly stuck at STOPPING.

Starting the same job from a plain `HttpServlet` it runs to completion immediately. Why is this so?

Comment: When you say a MessageListener, do you specifically mean something besides an MDB?   If so, that is probably the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an MDB to consume a JMS message within an EE application server, not your own MessageListener.  (See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageConsumer.html#setMessageListener-javax.jms.MessageListener-).)

Batch needs to run on a managed thread so that EE contexts are available so that EE APIs such as the **ManagedExecutorService** used as the batch "thread pool" will function correctly.

There will also be potential issues with other EE APIs besides batch (and potentially other app server features) when using non-managed threads, which is why the MDB is the necessary approach here.

Comment: Thank you Scott, I surely had gaps in my understanding of the EE environment. My MessageListener was running as `@javax.inject.Singleton` instance. 

Your three paragraphs have also answered more of my questions in mind.